# Запись результата из двух переменных

Tags: c#, datagrid, шифрование

У меня проблема с шифрованием текста, которое в принципе производится по таблице, где букве соответствует число, а для некоторых сочетаний отдельно число выделено, как например для CON=55 (а А = 1). Вот, допустим, ввожу слово "acon", проверяю сначала наличие слогов:

```
string result = "";
string text = textBox2.Text;
text=text.Replace("con", "55");
text = text.Replace("et", "8");
```

А потом иду просто по отдельным буквам так:

```
for (int i = 0; i < text.Length; i++)
{
    string letter = text[i].ToString();
    foreach (DataGridViewColumn column in dataGridView1.Columns)
    {
        if (column.HeaderText == letter)
        {
            string cellValue = dataGridView1.CurrentRow.Cells[column.Index].Value.ToString();
            var values = cellValue.Split(' ');
            int index = rnd.Next(values.Length);
            result += values[index];
        }
    }
}
listBox1.Items.Add(result);
```

Никак не пойму, как выполнить слияние этих переменных, чтобы в итоге вывелось "155", подскажите...

Comment: А что выводит то сейчас и что такое rnd.Next(values.Length)?

Answer (score 1):

Я давно писал на C# но разве == сравнивает строки по значению, мне кажется надо писать

```
if (letter.Equals(column.HeaderText))
```

Если я правильно понял задание, то согласен, самое простое это в строке заменить все слоги на цифры, но надо учитывать, что слоги в строке могут повторяться и что надо начинать проверку с самого длинного слога и заканчивая самым коротким. Потом да, можно в один проход по строке проверяя на каждой итерации что символ является не цифрой то удалять его, а на его место вставлять число.

```
if(text[i]<'0'||text[i]>'9') {...}
```

Правда не представляю как вы восстанавливать будете исходное сообщение...

Comment: Ваш вариант с if работает точно так же как и мой) А вот как все-таки реализовать просмотр слогов сначала? Вот это как-то же по-другому должно записываться?
string text = textBox2.Text;
text=text.Replace("con", "55");
text = text.Replace("et", "8");
И как мне объединить вывод переменных text и result?

Comment: помогите пожалуйста, очень нужно!

Comment: @Raskilas, вот я делаю условие на проверку наличия слогов
if (text.IndexOf("con") > -1 || text.IndexOf("et") > -1)
А дальше как быть с циклом? Вот так можно найти индекс, с которого начинается слог, например для con:  int alfa = text.IndexOf("con"); а в общем случае как быть тоже не знаю, у меня же несколько слогов

Comment: В .NET для строк переопределён оператор == таким образом, что выполняет вызов Equals, который производит посимвольное сравнение без учёта культуры.